# Thread in Tcl is not really working as C threads

Tags: multithreading, scripting, tcl

In Tclsh thread package, a created thread is not sharing variables and namespace with main thread, which is quite different from C implementation of threads. Why is this contradiction in tcl thread design. Or am i missing something in the code? Does all scripting language have similar threaded design with them?

Below is the quote from Tcl thread documentation PDF,

> thread::create
>   . All other extensions must be loaded
>   explicitly into each thread
>   that needs to use them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually similar to one way you'd use threads in C: message passing. Of course, you can use threads in other ways as well in C. But message passing is one way to completely avoid deadlocks since the semaphores/mutexes can be completely managed around the message queues and you don't need them anywhere else in your code.

This is in fact what Tcl implements at the C level. And it is in fact why it was done this way: to avoid the need for semaphores (to prevent the user form deadlocking himself).

Most other scripting languages simply provide a thin wrapper around pthreads so you can deadlock yourself if you're not careful. I remember way back in the early 2000s the general advice for threaded programming in C and most other languages is to implement a message passing architecture to avoid deadlocks.

Since tcl generally takes the view that API exposed at the script level should be high level, the thread implementation was implemented with a message passing architecture built-in. Of course, there is also the convenient fact that it also avoids having to make the tcl interpreter thread-safe (thus introducing mutexes all over the interpreter source code).

Making interpreters thread-safe is non trivial. Some languages suffer mysterious crashes to this day when running threaded applications. Some languages took over a decade to iron out all threading bugs. Tcl just decided not to try. The tcl interpreter is small enough and spins up quite fast so the solution was to simply run one interpreter per thread.

Comment: Javascript recently also decided to go the tcl route. Threads in javascript (webworkers) run in their own environments. But that was done for a different reason - security.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a [contradiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction). *It's just a different model.* It has its advantages and its disadvantages. The key disadvantage you already know: scripts and variables are not shared (unless you take special steps). The key advantage is that the Tcl implementation has no big global locks, and that makes it much easier to use multi-core hardware effectively and means that there are *very* few gotchas when doing so. Contrast this with the [Python Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), which is necessary because Python uses the C-like global shared state model.

At the low level, Tcl's threading is strongly isolated with plenty of thread-shared variables behind the scenes so that locks can be avoided (including in the memory management a lot of time, which would otherwise be a key bottleneck). Inter-thread communications are based on top of Tcl's built-in event queueing system; when two threads communicate, one sends a message and (optionally) waits for the other to respond, with the receiver getting the message placed on its internal queue of events until it is in a state that is ready to handle it. This does slow down inter-thread communications, but is much faster when they're *not* communicating.